# Can JAX-WS host "web" service in desktop program?

Tags: java, .net, wcf, web-services, jax-ws

Can Java (JAX-WS) host "web" service in desktop program?
For example .net wcf can host services anywhere.
Tnx all.

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible using the [`javax.xml.ws.Endpoint`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/Endpoint.html) class (and the server from the JDK). You can learn more about this in the following [article](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/07/03/jax-ws-web-services-without-ee-containers.html).

Another option would be to use an embeddable container like Jetty, to embed it in your desktop app and to deploy your JAX-WS web services on it.

Answer (score 0):

As long as there is a tool to handle HTTP - yes. [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/) can be embedded in desktop applications. [Here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/standalone-http-transport.html) is some documentation about standalone http transport with cxf.